# Count the number of field having value populated except NULL using lambda function throughout all rows

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for having a look at this question. I am creating a logic using lambda, that runs through all the rows and counts the number of the field having value except NA. As you can see in the given example.

```
Input : 

project_id   project_a   project_b   project_c   project_d   project_e
     1             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes
     2             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes
     3             NA          Yes        Yes         NA       Yes
     4             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes
     5             NA          Yes        Yes         NA       Yes

Desired Output :

project_id   project_a   project_b   project_c   project_d   project_e    field_populated
     1             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes              5
     2             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes              5
     3             NA          Yes        Yes         NA       Yes              3
     4             Yes         Yes        Yes         NA       Yes              5
     5             NA          Yes        Yes         NA       Yes              4
```

I have tried using the following code but facing some issues.

```
proj_table['field_populated'] = proj_table['project_id', 'project_a', 'project_b','project_c, 'project_d','project_e].apply(lambda x: x+1 if x != "NA" or np.nan else x)
```

Comment: I guess you have made a typo the value of `project_id=3` should be `4`?

Comment: Yes, there is @ShubhamSharma. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it, you can count non-null values of your dataframe and populate a new column using, `count`, and perform operation along rows (`axis=1`).

`filter(like='project')` will consider only columns with 'project' in case you have more columns in your actual `df`.

```
df['field_populated'] = df.filter(like='project').count(axis=1)
```

Which prints:

```
df

   project_id project_a project_b  ... project_d  project_e field_populated
0           1       Yes       Yes  ...       NaN        Yes               5
1           2       Yes       Yes  ...       NaN        Yes               5
2           3       NaN       Yes  ...       NaN        Yes               4
3           4       Yes       Yes  ...       NaN        Yes               5
4           5       NaN       Yes  ...       NaN        Yes               4
```

Answer (score 0):

As sophocles said, there is no need for a lambda function here. But, in case that you intended to apply a lambda function for learning reasons, you could do a simple lambda that counts how many non "X" values are there in each row. Furthermore, if you wanted to do it even more "lambd-ish", you could check if the values are "NA" or not with another function too!

Here's a little example:

```
import pandas as pd

not_NA = lambda column: 1 if column != "NA" else 0

count_NA = lambda row: sum(row.apply(not_NA))

df = pd.DataFrame([["1","2","3","4","5"], ["1","2","NA","4","5"], ["1","2","3","4","NA"], ["NA","2","NA","4","5"]], columns=list(["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]))

df['field_populated'] = df.apply(count_NA, axis=1)
```

Which prints:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5  field_populated
0    1    2    3    4    5                5
1    1    2   NA    4    5                4
2    1    2    3    4   NA                4
3   NA    2   NA    4    5                3
```

Note that in the lambda function "not_NA" you can also add other values that you want to discard in case you need to.